# How to pass a header once when sending a list of JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm passing a list of json objects from the client to server.
Is there any way or standard to send the headers only once instead of passing it in each json object (more as a csv style where you pass the header and then the list of objects containing the content only)?

for example:

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

If I have 10,000 employees to pass, repeating each time the headers ("fisrtName" and "lastName") is wasteful.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you are trying to acieve?

Comment: you want to pass a data which kinda looks like a table? (first rows => 'firstname', 'lastname', then below the header are the values, much like a table)

Comment: exactly, this is my goal. I'm looking for some library which does that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of firstName and Lastname and pass data like this,

```
{
    "employees": {
        "firstName" : ["John", "Anna", "Peter"],
        "lastName" : ["Doe", "Smith", "Jones"]
    }
}
```